# Run Batchfile on a VM from a shared folder

Tags: powershell, command-line, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I created batch files on a certain folder on my Virtual Machine (windows). These batch files have Commandline scripts + Powershell scripts. I shared this folder with my Windows user and gave my user all permissions. However, when I run the batch file with my user from the shared folder it won't run (apparently because it is trying to run them from my local command line). 
My question is: is there a way to run these batch files from the shared folder?

The reason I am doing this is because I have a bot (automation anywhere) that has it's own windows user and I need this bot to be able to run these batch files.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you mean you want the scripts to run on the machine where the shared folder is stored and not the remote machine you are accessing it from?  If so, then you should look at [PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6).  If not, please clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @boxdog yes I want to scripts to run on the machine where the shared folder is stored and not the remote machine I am accessing it from.

Comment: Where does your bot run?